# mysql select next row without knowing the id

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy way to do both these queries in one:

```
$name = 'somename';

$id = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = $name'));

$next_id = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > $id ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 1'));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subquery to get the ID, then >= the selected ID, then limit 2

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = '$name') ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect... made a mistake my original query, meant to have LIMIT 0, 1. So SELECT id FROM table WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = '$name') ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, 1 would work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
$next_id = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT id FROM table WHERE id > (SELECT id FROM table WHERE name = $name LIMIT 1,1) ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1, 1));
```